# Why other resource file not shown

Tags: c#, winforms

I add several resources file (.resx) to my project.
If resources file be in root everything is fine, but if i move it to a folder, when i want to set image for a picture box, i cant find my (.resx) file in select resource wizard.
Only default resource file exist, and i must set it manually.
Like this:

```
this.mnuFinancial Image = global::myProject.myCustomResource.myImage;
```

Comment: *Have you tried turning it off and on again?* (Visual Studio, that is)

Comment: You'll have to follow my doctor's usual advice: "if it hurts then don't do it".  VS just doesn't support this.